# Proving a set is Borel

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove that if $B \subseteq \mathbb R$ is a Borel set, then $B \times \mathbb R$ is a Borel in $\mathbb R^2$, i.e. $B \times \mathbb R \in B_2 $

I'm still trying to understand the definition properly. Please can someone show this. It would help me so much.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set is a Borel set if it is in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

So, $B \subseteq \Bbb R$ is a Borel set if $B \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$.

What is $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$?  It is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open subsets of $\Bbb R$ (i.e., the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets).

You need to show $B \times \Bbb R$ is a Borel set in $\Bbb R^{2}$, i.e., $B \times \Bbb R \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^{2})$.

But $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^{2})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open subsets of $\Bbb R^{2}$.  If you know that $\mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^{2}) = \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R) \times \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$ (where the RHS is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by measurable rectangles), then the problem becomes easy, because $B \times \Bbb R \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R) \times \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: wait so is that all there is to the proof? Is $B(\mathbb R^2) =B_2$?

Comment: @cooldudeman Yes, $B_{2}$ should be alternate notation for $B(\Bbb R^{2})$.  Of course, you would have to know that $B(\Bbb R) \times B(\Bbb R) = B(\Bbb R^{2})$, and it's more likely you should prove this (or at least prove $B(\Bbb R) \times B(\Bbb R) \subseteq B(\Bbb R^{2})$).

Comment: This answer is from 6 years ago, but I think it's partially incorrect (in the wording, the idea is correct). $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is not the same as $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^2$. The set $(0,1)\times (0,1) \cup (2,3)\times (2,3)$ is in the former, but not the latter. In fact the latter does not even contain all the open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and it's not even an algebra.

Answer (score 2):

The following proof is not the shortest, but (for me at least) makes things nicely intuitive.

We begin with a description of the Borel sets as a *hierarchy*:

- The **$\Sigma^0_1$-sets** are the open sets.
- For $\alpha$ a countable ordinal $>1$, the **$\Sigma^0_\alpha$-sets** are the sets of the form $B=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} A_i$, where each $A_i$ is the complement of a $\Sigma^0_\beta$-set for some $\beta<\alpha$.
- Then we can prove:

  > The **Borel sets** are the sets which are $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ for some countable ordinal $\alpha$.

(This is a good exercise if you haven't seen it before.)

Countable ordinals are often annoyingly abstract, but the *hierarchy* they provide allows us to use transfinite induction to prove results about Borel sets. For the specific question you're interested in, try proving the following stronger result by induction on $\alpha$:

> Show that if $A$ is a $\Sigma^0_\alpha$-subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $A\times\mathbb{R}$ is a $\Sigma^0_\alpha$-subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

*Base case*: if $A$ is open, is $A\times\mathbb{R}$ open?

*Induction step*: Suppose (IH) that $\alpha$ is some countable ordinal such that for every $\beta<\alpha$, if $A$ is a $\Sigma^0_\beta$ subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $A\times\mathbb{R}$ is a $\Sigma^0_\beta$ subset of $\mathbb{R}^2 $. Now let $A$ be $\Sigma^0_\alpha$. By definition, this means $$A=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} B_i,$$ where $B_i$ is the complement of a $\Sigma^0_{\beta_i}$ set $C_i$, $\beta_i<\alpha$. Look at $$A\times\mathbb{R}=[\bigcup B_i]\times\mathbb{R}=\bigcup[B_i\times\mathbb{R}]=\bigcup [C_i\times \mathbb{R}]^c.$$ Do you see how to continue?